# ogr2ogr Spatialite to csv very slow

Tags: csv, spatialite, ogr2ogr, performance

I am using ogr2ogr to extract point data from a Spatialite db to a csv file:-

ogr2ogr -f "CSV" commandtmp.csv dtm2.sqlite -lco GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ -progress -explodecollections

the Spatialite db is 7GB and it takes days to extract the point data to a 15GB csv file.

Are there any ways to speed this up?

Comment: run top or glances and see what your choke point is during the process. disk, CPU or memory.

Answer (score 1):

It works quite fast for me. I used http://download.geofabrik.de/europe-latest.osm.pbf as sample data and converted the points layer into Spatialite database as

```
ogr2ogr -f sqlite -dsco spatialite=yes europe_points.sqlite europe-latest.osm.pbf points -progress -lco spatial_index=no
```

Then I created CSV file as

```
ogr2ogr -f "CSV" commandtmp.csv europe_points.sqlite -lco GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ -progress -explodecollections -sql "select geometry from points"
```

It took only 20 minutes to write out the 1 GB sized CSV file. I used GDAL-devel version on Windows.